# gke autoscaler is not scaling down the nodes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a standard gke cluster with one worker node and implemented cluster autoscaling with optimize-utilization profile

Than I deployed my angular application with 1 replica , after I scaled my replica to 7 , a new one worker node got created which handled the pods , when I scaled down the replica to 1 , I noticed that my Autoscaler is not deleting the other worker node as one node is enough to handle one replica.

here you can see the image

[2 nodes with 1 pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CMKg.png)

my question is why it not scaling down , and what is the solution to scale it down.

[log-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNC49.png)

[log-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFKKP.png)

by checking autoscaler log it says no.scale.down.node.pod.kube.system.unmovable please help me to solve this , kubernetes should decrease the 2nd node as one node is enough for one pod.

I am tried to add pod disruption budget for kube-system but not worked for me , I am expecting some solution to bring back my cluster to one node from two nodes.